# How do you report rude answers?

Tags: support, flagging

In the main Stack Overflow site there's a flag through which we can report obsolete or non-constructive or rude comments, or various options on questions and answers, to contact a moderator. In this site, I don't find anything like that. What can I do?
In main Stack overflow I see the flag symbol even before I have achieved the reputation .(Does the visibility of the symbol depends on the Reputation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature works in the same way on all sites: click the “flag” button on question and answers, or the flag-shaped icon on comments. But it [requires at least 15 reputation points](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), which you don't have yet on this site.

I think that the idea of requiring a bit of reputation for flagging is that we want all users to start with the core functions of the site: asking, answering, editing. Another reason is that some users raise abusive flags; if raising an unlimited number of flags was as easy as creating accounts repeatedly, they could overload moderators (posts and edits are reviewed by more people and have more rate limits in place, so they scale better).

In the meantime, if the issue can be raised publicly, you have two options:

- With 20 reputation points on any site, you can drop in to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science). The chatroom isn't very active, but you can leave a message and one of us will usually come along later that day.
- With 5 reputation points on this site, you can post on meta.

If you lack the requisite reputation, or if the issue is confidential, you can [contact Stack Exchange directly](https://cs.stackexchange.com/contact). Explain what the problem is, why it must be dealt with in confidence (if this isn't obvious), and why you can't flag.

Comment: @user285oo6 13 is less than 15. You need at least 15 reputation points.

Comment: I clearly understood but my question was whether the Visibility of the Flag option depends on the Reputation(If the rep is 15 only then will the option be visible)

Comment: @user285oo6 Yes, the button will only be visible when you have enough reputation to use it.